# Why does my heating system only blow cold air?

Tags: heating

My heating system only blows out cold air, not hot.  I've left it on for a good 15 minutes to see if it will warm up, and I get nothing but cold air.  I've even put it on *Auto* and waited some more, but still all I get is cold air.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of heating system you have.  It's impossible to even guess without knowing that.

Comment: -1 Without more details, this question can't be answered and should likely be closed.

Comment: Pinknblu all answers and comments already posted are the only thing anyone can say unless you describe the system you are refering to that won't warm you up. Please try giving all pertanent information if you actually need the answers you're looking for. Chances are by now the heat in on though. ;) :)

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3653/why-is-my-furnace-blowing-cold-air

Answer (score 5):

Several possible issues:

1. Bad thermostat
2. Pilot light out (if a gas furnace with a pilot light)
3. Heating element out (if electrical furnace)
4. It's cold outside (if heat pump - coupled w/ #3)
5. Electronic ignition shot (gas furnace w/ no pilot light)

Without more information, that's the best guess I can make.

Comment: 6. You have mistaken the heating system for the air conditioner.

Comment: Technically that would be the other way around, but - LOL

Comment: A bad high limit switch would also cause this. however, if the limit switch was bad the blower would never shut off.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off the furnace, remove the thermostat, touch the R and W wires together (as well as R and G), and then turn it back on and see what you get.  If this works, then your thermostat isn't calling for heat correctly, but the fan is operating when it attempts to.